# DirectMessageListenerContainer is it possible to use with BatchMessageListener

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

In current version org.springframework.amqp: 2.2.2 BatchMessageListener contains:

```
@Override
default void onMessage(Message message) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Should never be called by the container");
}
```

and it is correct, but when I use it in DirectMessageListenerContainer

```
listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new BatchMessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMessageBatch(List<Message> messages) {
      ....
    }
}
```

and I have got UnsupportedOperationException("Should never be called by the container");

Answer (score 0):

`BatchMessageListener` is not supported by the `DirectMessagelistenerContainer` because the listener is called directly on amqp-client thread for each received message.

Comment: and it's not possible to process batch in one thread? How I understand I can get it by onMessage method and use deBatch from BatchingStrategy. But it doesn't look right.

Comment: Yes; we could support deBatching producer batches in the DMLC; but we can't support consumer-side batching of incoming records. The simple container supports both batching modes, but the batch listener was added specifically for consumer-side batching and debatching producer batches into a List<?> was an added bonus; but we failed to add support for that to the DMLC; please open a GitHub issue and we'll add it.

Comment: FYI, debatching as a `List<?>` is already supported when using `@RabbitListener` with a DMLC: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#receiving-batch.